# Rotational Energy homework question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

A hollow sphere rolls along floor and goes up 30 degree incline, how far up does it stop?

Ok so from what i know you need conservation of energy:

$mgh=$rotational energy

And $h$ is $d\sin(30)$, where $d$ is the distance up the hill.

So you get $mgd\sin(30)=\frac{I\omega^2}{2}$

And since $I$ is $2/3mR^2$ for hollow spheres, you can sub it in and cancel out $m$.

$gd\sin(30)=\frac{R^2\omega^2}{3}$

But the question is, since it does not give you the radius of the sphere, I do not see how you can solve for angular velocity from the $5\text{ m/s}$ they give you?

How should this question be approached?

Also, how to you format the text and equations to look good? I looked online but found nothing.
Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question to format the equations.  Click on the edit button and you can see how it is typed.  The format used is MathJax, and it mostly follows the rules of Latex math formatting.

Comment: What is the relationship between $v$ and $\omega$ for a rolling sphere?

Comment: okay, what is 5 m/s, is that the velocity of the ball before it climbs the slope ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is the kinetic energy of the center of mass translating. You need

$$ KE = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $$

A hollow sphere has $I=\frac{2}{3}m r^2$ and pure rolling means $v = \omega r$. So the end result you get

$$ KE = \frac{5}{6} m \omega^2 r^2 = \frac{5}{6} m v^2 $$